# Oracle PL/SQL - Receive a list of values as IN parameter, use them in the WHERE clause and return the results in a procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need to create an Oracle procedure that receives a list of values, let's say Customer IDs, and uses those IDs in the WHERE clause of a SELECT statetement searching for all those Customer IDs in a table. The resulting columns and rows of this table must be returned by the procedure to the caller.
The quantity of Customer IDs is variable.

I imagine I should use cursors for this and the procedure would be declared similarly to this:
`CREATE PROCEDURE (c_customers IN  SYS_REFCURSOR, c_results OUT sys_refcursor) IS BEGIN ...` but I don’t know how to manipulate those cursors.

Comment: you better use a collection types,  e.g. `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_number is TABLE OF NUMBER;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an alternative solution is to use the collections:

First you have to create a global collection as a type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tab_number is TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

you can then use it as a type of your arguments in your procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YOUR_PROC_NAME (
    in_id_list IN            tab_number ,
    C_RESULTS     OUT           SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
    OPEN C_RESULTS FOR 
    SELECT *
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
     WHERE YOUR_COLUMN IN (
              SELECT column_value from table(in_id_list)
       );

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to take customer ids as string input.

see if the following can help:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YOUR_PROC_NAME (
    C_CUSTOMERS   IN            VARCHAR2,
    C_RESULTS     OUT           SYS_REFCURSOR
) IS
BEGIN
    OPEN C_RESULTS FOR 
    SELECT *
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
     WHERE YOUR_COLUMN IN (
              SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(C_CUSTOMERS, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
       );

END;
```

Cheers!!